# Where can I find a place id on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to get the place images according to the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests).

According to this document I need the "place id" of the place.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Where can I find the `placeid`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The place_id is in the [SearchResults](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResults) from any of the [SearchRequests](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResponses):

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870775,
               "lng" : 151.199025
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
         "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 270,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
               "width" : 519
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",  // <----------------------------------------------
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "alt_ids" : [
            {
               "place_id" : "D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
               "scope" : "APP"
            }
         ],
```

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to find a place ID here:
https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#find-id

Answer (score 4):

The above solution works in most cases but sometimes fails when you have some individuals using the same address as a business. In case you have exhausted the options from the API and manual search provided in the Google documentation [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#find-id) Or [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

You can use the manual suggestion provided at this page which has always worked for me https://www.launch2success.com/guide/cant-find-google-places-id-trick-finding-google-places-id/

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: this method works even when the google tool can't find the place id

Answer (score 2):

You may want a Place ID [Text search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) by searching the place name.

Your sample request may look like

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=fish+market+sydney&key="YOUR_API_KEY"

You will find the "place_id" in the return JSON String.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the `TextSeach` option or else try the `Nearbysearch` option which I have mentioned below maybe it works for you.

1[.https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?query={address}&key={_apiConfig.Key}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?query=%7Baddress%7D&key=%7B_apiConfig.Key%7D)

2.[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query={address}&key={_apiConfig.Key}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%7Baddress%7D&key=%7B_apiConfig.Key%7D)

In response, you will get all information with a place id which is help full.