# Where do I find my google places 'place_id'?

Tags: google-places-api

I have been searching for a few hours now and cannot find the 'place_id' related to my google places. I have an API key setup and just need to get the place_id now. Any ideas?

Comment: Here you go, it's in the URL as a parameter on a request: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030507/where-i-can-find-a-place-id-on-google-maps

Comment: Funny, I was on that link earlier today, but your comment helped me understand it a bit better. Have it now, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed this is just links for the Google API [Documentaion for the searches](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search), the general [place documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) however more specifically the [Search Results](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResults) and [Search Responses](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResponses) documentation is more useful as it shows the examples etc.

A quote from the documentation

> The Places API currently returns a place_id in all responses, and accepts a placeid in the Place Details and Place Delete requests.

See also; [Where I can find a place id on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030507/where-i-can-find-a-place-id-on-google-maps) from the stack exchange